# aggregates variables into new variable

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataframe which includes 30 different countries. I want to group these countries into 5 new values.

For example,

I have

```
China
Japan
US
Canada
 ....
```

Aggregate to new variables:

```
Asia 
Asia
North America
North America
 ....
```

One solution I am thinking about is using nested ifelse. However it seems that I need 4 or 5 nested ifelse to get what I need. I don't think that's a good way. I want to know other efficient solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use a key/value dataset. The `countrycode_data` from the `library(countrycode)` can be used for this purpose.  We match the 'country.name' column in 'countrycode_data' with the example data column ('Col1').  If there are no matches, it will return `NA`.  Using the OP's example, 'US' returns `NA` as the 'country.name' is 'United States'.  But, we can get the abbreviated form using the 'cowc' column.  However, the abbreviated version is also `USA`, which we can find using `grep`.  I would suggest to `grep` all `NA` elements in 'indx'.  The 'indx' can be used for returning 'region' from the 'countrycode_data'.

```
library(countrycode)
indx <- match(df1$Col1, countrycode_data$country.name)
pat <- paste0('^',paste(df1$Col1[is.na(indx)], collapse='|'))
indx[is.na(indx)] <- grep(pat, countrycode_data$cowc)
countrycode_data$region[indx]
#[1] "Eastern Asia"     "Eastern Asia"     "Northern America" "Northern America"
```

NOTE: This will return a bit more specific than the general 'Asia'.

If we use the 'continent' column,

```
countrycode_data$continent[indx]
#[1] "Asia"     "Asia"     "Americas" "Americas"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("China", "Japan", "US", "Canada")),
.Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the `recode` function from the `car` package:

```
library(car)
dat$Region <- recode(dat$Country, "c('China', 'Japan') = 'Asia'; c('US','Canada') = 'North America'")

  Country        Region
1   China          Asia
2   Japan          Asia
3      US North America
4  Canada North America
```

Answer (score 0):

They are just 30 countries and so you can make few vectors like shown below, create a new column and replace according to the vectors.

```
asia <- c("India", "china")
NorthAmerica <- c("US", "canada")
df$continent <- df$countries
df$continent <- with(df, replace(continent, countries%in%asia,"Asia"))
df$continent <- with(df, replace(continent, countries%in%NorthAmerica,"North America"))
```

Answer (score 0):

'continent' is a built-in destination code of the [countrycode package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countrycode/index.html). You can pass a vector of country names and get a vector of continent names back with...

```
library(countrycode)
countries <- c('China', 'Japan', 'US', 'Canada')
countrycode(countries, 'country.name', 'continent')
```

returns...

```
[1] "Asia"     "Asia"     "Americas" "Americas"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when using Veera's and Jay's approaches to define column as a vector in order to allow for the change of a column's levels:

```
df$continent <- as.factor(as.vector(df$countries))
```